# How to set 1/3/5 years billing period in Paypal express checkout PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using paypal as payment gateway and want to create recurring profile like

- 1 year plan for $20
- 3 year plan for $40
- 5 year plan for $50

but when i'm adding `BILLINGPERIOD=year&BILLINGFREQUENCY=3` as params,
getting error from paypal api :

And getting Error :

```
Billing frequency must be > 0 and be less than or equal to one year
Error Message: Invalid billing frequencyError Code: 11516
Error Severity Code: Error
```

Please help me here.

Comment: Maybe what you want isn't possible!  YOu might need to implement your own recurring charge mechanism.  Perhaps you should try paypal support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the paypal api, you need to create your own mechanism.

From the paypal api:

> The combination of BillingPeriod and BillingFrequency cannot exceed
>   one year.

If the `billingperiod` is `Month` you can set the `billingfrequency` to e.g. 1, 4, 9 and 12 but not to 13.

If the `billingperiod` is `Year` you can set the `billingfrequency`only to 1.

Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: can you suggest me anything on this?

Comment: Sadly I can't think of a technical solution for this problem. You would have to make sure your users pay the subscription for 1, 3 or 5 years. Let them sign a contract.

Comment: Talked with paypal team they also said it's api restriction you can't add more than a year.

Comment: Looking for possible solution like reference transaction and billing agreement but again  transaction id will expire after 2 years so no use for 3/5 years plans.